# Classical geometry statement in modern terminology

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Given two line segments $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$, it's always possible to find a third line segment whose length divides evenly into the first two. In modern terminology, if we assign $x = \overline{AB}$ and $y = \overline{CD}$, than the above statement is equivalent to asserting that $x = ay$, where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I'm having difficulty understanding why these two statements are equivalent, mainly because I find the phrasing of the first sentence confusing. If $\overline{CD}$ is a rational multiple of $\overline{AB}$, then why can we always find a third line segment that "evenly" divides into them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a = \frac p q$, then $x$ and $y$ are both integral multiples of $\frac y q$ by multplying by $p$ and by $q$ respectively. So here, $\frac p q$ is the length of the third length.

This is what meant by “evenly dividing”: You can use the third length to measure both other lengths, it introduces a suitable measure, just like inches measure feet and feet measure yards.

The statement is essentially that the lengths are [commensurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_%28mathematics%29) and is equivalent to saying that the euclidian algorithm for these lengths works: The third line segment is literally their greatest common divisor, i.e. the greatest length which measures both of the others.

---

And also, it is *not* always possible to find such a third length – the diagonal of a square is *never* commensurable with its sides which was exactly the unexpected discovery that unsettled the Pythagoreans back in their days. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippasus#Irrational_numbers) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#History).

Comment: Good answer, thanks I understand now.